# Meaning of the word "as"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, as

**As** we usually think of dreams, they go on in the minds of people who are actually lying in a real bed in a real house, even if in the dream they are running away from a homicidal lawnmower through the streets of Kansas City. We also assume that normal dreams depend on what is happening in the dreamer's brain while he sleeps."

I don't know the meaning of the word "As" in the first sentence. Could you help me please! I think it means "when". Is it right?

Comment: It means roughly "in the manner in which".

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentenece:

> As we usually think of dreams ...

means "The way in which we usually think of dreams is..."

This sentence sounds more in an academic than a colloquial  register to me.

Answer (score 0):

It means "We usually think of dreams as going on ..." or alternatively "We usually think of dreams as if they were going on ..."

I have never heard the phrasing that you are asking about in colloquial American English.

Comment: We use "as" that way a lot here (US), don't we?: "**As** is our custom, each speaker will have 2 minutes ..." "**As** Aesop says, look before you leap.", etc.

Comment: My point is that a hypothetical is involved here, namely how dreams work. And we introduce hypotheticals with an implied or explicit "if" or "as if." Your examples are fine, and I do not dispute them, but they have nothing to do with hypotheticals.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates progress of one action based on the progress of another action. That sentence is still complicated to me because it seems to be very poetic.

Comment: That is not the meaning of "as" used here.